# Why does re.findall() return an empty list in this case and a list with an empty string in another?

Tags: python, regex

`re.findall(r'[^-](-*)$', '----')` returns an empty list `[]`.

Meanwhile, `re.findall(r'[^-](-*)$', '----343')` returns a list with an empty string `['']`.

There is no match in either cases. Why does re.findall() return an empty list in the first case, but a list with an empty string in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does this because when you say `(-*)` you are matching *zero* or more occurences of `-`, whenever these hyphens follow a character that is not a `-`. In the first example there are no characters that are not `-` so nothing matches, thus the empty list. In the second example, there are three characters (the digits) that are not hyphens, so `(-*)` matches the last `3` followed by zero occurences of `-`.

Answer (score 1):

`$` matches the end of the line, which has zero characters. In the first case there are no matches because the end of the line is preceded by a dash (`-`) which you've negated with `[^-]`. In the second, the end of line is preceded by a non-dash character which matches the regex.